# Help in the demonstration of Ibrahim Assem "Algèbres et modules" Lemma 3.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I'm studying algebras and modules with the book "Algèbres et modules" written by Ibrahim Assem, at the page 131 (chapter 5) there's the lemma 3.1: if $\varphi:\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,-)\xrightarrow{\sim} \operatorname{Hom}_A(N,-)$ then $M \xrightarrow{\sim} N$ where $\xrightarrow{\sim}$ is an isomorphism.

The part I don't understand of the demonstration is why this square is commutative:

[image]

he just claims it is commutative without explaining why, and I can't see it.

Comment: This is the definition of "natural transformation" -- in other words, (part of) what it means for $\varphi$ to be a natural transformation is that this square commutes for any $f : M \to N$.

Comment: The natural transformation you talk about is what he defines as functorial morphism?

Comment: Probably yes! But you can make sure by reading the definition. Compare to https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_naturelle if you like.

Comment: Although it is true that the diagram is a part of the fact that $\varphi$ is a natural transformation, I think you should definitely work out why the diagram actually commutes! In fact, you should be able to show that $\varphi$ is a natural transformation by showing the more general diagram commutes. 

You probably know this but just in case: to prove a diagram commutes, say, the above diagram, just take any $\alpha \in Hom_A(M,M)$ and by chasing down its images in two directions, prove the two images are the same in $Hom_A(N,N)$.

Comment: Please check out example 1.3 at page 52.